# 'And they are bought, like...'. Extra meaning of the verb 'buy'?

Tags: speech

Please help me to understand the beginning of this sentence (before "as soon"). I guess it doesn't carry much meaning but i still wonder what this part means:

> "And they are bought, like they run from, well from they don't, as soon as they learn to walk they're running and they run their whole lives and they run like a hundred miles is just like a walk in the park to them. "

The whole dialogue is here: http://elllo.org/english/1151/T1200-Julia-Sport.html

Comment: I think it is probably either a typo or a mishearing of 'brought'. I can't listen to the interview but it reads as though she interrupted herself part way through saying 'brought up running' or 'brought up thinking running is normal' or something along those lines.

Comment: I've now listened to it several times and conclude that the transcription is mistaken. I think the word she interrupted herself in was more likely 'born', possibly 'And they are born running'.

Answer (score 2):

Julia does not put her sentences together well; when she said *bought*, she completely misspoke.  If we could ask her, she might not even be able to say what she was thinking of, and why that word might have come out of her mouth.